# Where to set Value for Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure.Utils.GetAppSetting on local machine?

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot

I downloaded the sample code from azure's bot app, and there is a line which i'm not sure where is the config value should be store. i try not to change the code as later i need publish back into azure server. So for this line

```
var qnaKBId = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAKnowledgebaseId");
```

Where should i create the variable for above when i need to code on **my local machine**?

I tried create the variable in web.config but it getting null. and the [document](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d2/dd8/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_azure_1_1_utils.html#ac2edbe4d27f0a3c1d98f2815f767db5e) not specify any detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In documentation, we can find that [Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure.Utils](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d2/dd8/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_builder_1_1_azure_1_1_utils.html#ac2edbe4d27f0a3c1d98f2815f767db5e) is a utility class for bots **running on Azure**.

> I tried create the variable in web.config but it getting null.

If you’d like to run your bot application on local and access settings from your web.config file, you can use the following code snippet to retrieve it in your bot application.

```
var qnaKBId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"];
```