# Connection issues with Translator Text API version 3.0 - Microsoft Azure QnA chat bot

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, chatbot

I want to connect my Azure QnA Chat Bot with the translation layer cognitive system. I am using this page as a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-csharp-translate

I am doing it in **C#** and on the **online code editor of Microsoft Azure**.

Unfortunately, I can not connect to the translation layer (at least it looks like that).

When I tried to debug it, I can see that it stops at this specific part:

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I checked the network timeout errors and there are many (20). All of them say "There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout".

I can "build.cmd" normally, without any errors, and when I try to do Debug.WriteLine or Console.WriteLine, nothing is printed out (I even tried in VS and Emulator)

The only thing that I am doing differently, compared to the above link, is that I defined the "host" and "key" outside of the private method:

```
private static async Task<string> TranslateQuestionToEnglish (...)
```

So, I take any word and want to translate it into English.
When I take out those two lines of the code, and test a method with static values, it obviously works (all together with QnA and everything else).

Later on, I am calling this method in "Task MessageReceivedAsync".

I created a translation cognitive service, and the only thing that I took from there is the first key from "Keys" and used it here in this method. **Is that the only thing that I need from created cognitive service??**

Another thing that I am not sure about, and if that thing is making a problems is that when I go to all resources, I can see that my qnatestbot(web app bot) and translator_test(cognitive services) are of type "global" location, while my qnatestbot(app service) is of type "west europe" location. Can the thing that they are in different regions make a problems? **Should I put all of them in West Europe (since I am in Germany)?**

Although, now that I look at the translator_test(cognitive services) endpoint, I can see that it is ...api.congitivemicrosft.com/.../**v1.0**.

**But, when I was creating a resource it was automatically created like this, without specifying it from my side?** **How can I change that?**

I hope that somebody successfully came across such an issue and can help me. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to connect my Azure QnA Chat Bot with the translation layer cognitive system. I am using this page as a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-csharp-translate

I try to create a sample to achieve your requirement: translate user inputs to English and pass translation text to QnAMaker dialog, the sample works fine both on local and Azure, you can refer to it.

***In MessagesController:***

```
[BotAuthentication]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{

    static string uri = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0&to=en";
    static string key = "{the_key}";

    /// <summary>
    /// POST: api/Messages
    /// receive a message from a user and send replies
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="activity"></param>
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
    {
        // check if activity is of type message
        if (activity.GetActivityType() == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            if (activity.Text != null)
            {
                var textinEN = await TranslateQuestionToEnglish(activity.Text);
                activity.Text = textinEN;
            }

            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootDialog());
        }
        else
        {
            HandleSystemMessage(activity);
        }
        return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
    }

    private static async Task<string> TranslateQuestionToEnglish(string text)
    {
        System.Object[] body = new System.Object[] { new { Text = text } };
        var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
        {
            request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
            request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
            request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);

            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
            var textinen = jsonResponse[0]["translations"][0]["text"].Value;

            return textinen;
        }
    }

    private Activity HandleSystemMessage(Activity message)
    {
        if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.DeleteUserData)
        {
            // Implement user deletion here
            // If we handle user deletion, return a real message
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle conversation state changes, like members being added and removed
            // Use Activity.MembersAdded and Activity.MembersRemoved and Activity.Action for info
            // Not available in all channels
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.ContactRelationUpdate)
        {
            // Handle add/remove from contact lists
            // Activity.From + Activity.Action represent what happened
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Typing)
        {
            // Handle knowing tha the user is typing
        }
        else if (message.Type == ActivityTypes.Ping)
        {
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

***In dialog:***

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        /* Wait until the first message is received from the conversation and call MessageReceviedAsync 
        *  to process that message. */
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        /* When MessageReceivedAsync is called, it's passed an IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>. To get the message,
            *  await the result. */
        var message = await result;

        var qnaAuthKey = GetSetting("QnAAuthKey"); 
        var qnaKBId = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAKnowledgebaseId");
        var endpointHostName = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAEndpointHostName");

        // QnA Subscription Key and KnowledgeBase Id null verification
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(qnaAuthKey) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(qnaKBId))
        {
            // Forward to the appropriate Dialog based on whether the endpoint hostname is present
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(endpointHostName))
                await context.Forward(new BasicQnAMakerPreviewDialog(), AfterAnswerAsync, message, CancellationToken.None);
            else
                await context.Forward(new BasicQnAMakerDialog(), AfterAnswerAsync, message, CancellationToken.None);
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Please set QnAKnowledgebaseId, QnAAuthKey and QnAEndpointHostName (if applicable) in App Settings. Learn how to get them at https://aka.ms/qnaabssetup.");
        }

    }

    private async Task AfterAnswerAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        // wait for the next user message
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public static string GetSetting(string key)
    {
        var value = Utils.GetAppSetting(key);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && key == "QnAAuthKey")
        {
            value = Utils.GetAppSetting("QnASubscriptionKey"); // QnASubscriptionKey for backward compatibility with QnAMaker (Preview)
        }
        return value;
    }
}

// Dialog for QnAMaker Preview service
[Serializable]
public class BasicQnAMakerPreviewDialog : QnAMakerDialog
{
    // Go to https://qnamaker.ai and feed data, train & publish your QnA Knowledgebase.
    // Parameters to QnAMakerService are:
    // Required: subscriptionKey, knowledgebaseId, 
    // Optional: defaultMessage, scoreThreshold[Range 0.0 – 1.0]
    public BasicQnAMakerPreviewDialog() : base(new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute(RootDialog.GetSetting("QnAAuthKey"), Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAKnowledgebaseId"), "No good match in FAQ.", 0.5)))
    { }
}

// Dialog for QnAMaker GA service
[Serializable]
public class BasicQnAMakerDialog : QnAMakerDialog
{
    // Go to https://qnamaker.ai and feed data, train & publish your QnA Knowledgebase.
    // Parameters to QnAMakerService are:
    // Required: qnaAuthKey, knowledgebaseId, endpointHostName
    // Optional: defaultMessage, scoreThreshold[Range 0.0 – 1.0]
    public BasicQnAMakerDialog() : base(new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute(RootDialog.GetSetting("QnAAuthKey"), Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAKnowledgebaseId"), "No good match in FAQ.", 0.5, 1, Utils.GetAppSetting("QnAEndpointHostName"))))
    { }

}
```

***Test result:***
[image]

***Note:*** We can use `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnAKnowledgebaseId"];` to access `QnAKnowledgebaseId` etc settings from web.config if run bot application on local. For more information, please refer to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51015338/where-to-set-value-for-microsoft-bot-builder-azure-utils-getappsetting-on-local/51015557#51015557).

Comment: Why are you creating a method and everything else in MessagesController. I have tried to create all of them in dialog.cs? 

Do you also think that the version thing that i explained above makes the problems as well? (Endpoint on created cognitive service says “v1.0”?

Comment: `Why are you creating a method and everything else in MessagesController. I have tried to create all of them in dialog.cs?` What's wrong? Any documentation indicates that I can not do that in MessagesController, and must put the logic in dialog.cs as you did?

Comment: `Do you also think that the version thing that i explained above makes the problems as well? ` Do you try to separately run "[Translate text with C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-csharp-translate)" with your key and check if it can work as expected?